# Incorrect fab position in fragment on startup

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I have a single fragment activity. fragment has a coordinator layout, fab as direct child of it and other views.

Activity Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment Layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableLinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/statistic_expand_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:ael_duration="150"
        app:ael_interpolator="accelerateDecelerate">

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/overall_statistic_bar_chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/statistic_small"/>

        <TextView
            style="@style/SmallTextTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_small"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/overall_statistic"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimary"/>

    </com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableLinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/statistic_expand_layout"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_tiny"
        android:layout_below="@id/statistic_expand_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_updown"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_standard"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/recycler_view"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I start activity with this fragment fab position is incorrect

[image: fab]

but when I press any button or view fab goes to its correct position in the right bottom corner. When I put this layout directly into activity fab position is always correct. Could anyone help me to figure out what is the problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when I press any button or view **fab goes to its correct position
>   in the right bottom corner**. **When I put this layout directly into
>   activity** fab position is always correct.

**Solution:** Here is the documentation of `AppBarLayout` and `CoordinatorLayout` which says how they should look like:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

         <!-- Your scrolling content -->

     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="match_parent">

         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                 ...
                 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

         <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                 ...
                 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So now, `RelativeLayout` in your design shouldn't be there. Put the `CoordinatorLayout` ***in the main layout*** of the `Activity` then, Try to use `AppBarLayout` when using `Toolbar` with `CoordinatorLayout` Because now `CoordinatorLayout` imagines the `RelativeLayout` as it's `AppBarLayout`.

And that's it. One more thing, Don't forget to add : `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your view under the `AppBarLayout`.

Let me know if you need any help or asking question.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but I did a mistake in question's description. Everything is fine not when I **put fragment's layout directly into activity** on fragment_container place, but when **I use fragment's layout as activity layout**. I need this RelativeLayout for positioning RecyclerView under Expandable layout when it's expanded.

Comment: Why you can't just use `CoordinatorLayout` inside **Activity Layout** and then putting `FloatingActionButton` in the right place? I'm just thinking about, Why you put the `Toolbar` inside a `LinearLayout` then for the fragment you are using `CoordinatorLayout` without a `Toolbar` and `AppBarLayout` !! I don't think if this layout design is right!

Comment: You'r right, i rewrote my activity layout with coordinator layout and now everything is fine. Thank you :)

Comment: @OlexiiMuraviov Awesome! Glad to heard that!